# How get value from localization?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

In my project I added tree global localization  files: Main.en-US.resx + Main.ru-Ru.resx + Main.uk-UA.resx in a folder App_GlobalResources.

On master page I set a culture into session like this:

```
protected void SetUSA_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Session["MyCulture"] = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            Server.Transfer(Request.Url.LocalPath);  
        }
```

and in sone class I init culture:

```
public class BaseForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            SetCulture();
            base.InitializeCulture();
        }

        private void SetCulture()
        {
            if (Session["myCulture"] != null) 
            {
                CultureInfo culture = (CultureInfo)Session["myCulture"];
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;                
            }
        }
```

some page inheritance this class:

```
public partial class ProductType : WrapperObjects.BaseForm
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

In code I tra to get value:

```
string ColumnName = CommonUtils.GetValueField("Main", "ProductTypeNameTitle", (CultureInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyCulture"]);


public static string GetValueField(string nameFileResources, string nameField, CultureInfo currentCulture)
        {
            try
            {
                if (currentCulture == null) currentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
                object fieldValue = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(nameFileResources, nameField, currentCulture);
                return fieldValue == null ? nameField : fieldValue.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return nameField;
            }
        }
```

but it wont work. I cant find my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing the session variables names `"myCulture"` and `"MyCulture"`.

Comment: Thanks. Small suggestion would be to use a constant. You can then just use that constant, it will save you from any typing errors (or if one occured you have a single place to fix it.).